# Asp.net Core 3.1 resolve Autofac container in startup and do some initialisation

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

net core 2.2 to 3.1 recently and having an issue with Autofact. I will need to do some initialisation after container is built.

In Asp.net Core 2.2, I have the following code in Startup.cs

```
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // do some other registr

        builder.Populate(services);

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        // Do some initialisation
        container.Resolve<IMessageQueueService>().RegisterBodiesListener();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
```

In the above code, `IMessageQueueService` is inherited from another interface `IService` and injected to container with

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType().Assembly)
            .As(typeof(IService))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

However, in Asp.net Core 3.1 since the `Build()` will be handled by Autofac itself, where I can do the initialisation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. There is a callback we can use when Autofac builds

```
builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c => {
            c.Resolve<IMessageQueueService>();
            });
```

Refer to [This Autofac Document](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#container-build-callbacks)

Comment: If all you needed to do was resolve the component, that's what "AutoActivate" is for. It's in the same doc you linked.